# Mac local (.dev) sites redirecting from http to https

Tags: macos, http, mamp

I have MAMP installed on my mac. Entry on host file **/etc/hosts**.

> 127.0.0.1       mysite.dev

I also enabled virtual hosts in httpd.cofig file.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My virtual host file is also correctly configured. This is what I have in **https.vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite"
  ServerName wiki.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to open http://mysite.dev using browser, the site is redirected to https://mysite.dev

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @herrbischoff - Thanks for sharing I know these.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like **.dev** is now a generic Top Level Domain owned in full by Google.

I changed host entry to .local and its working fine now,

.local, .test, .example should all work.

Comment: Does this fix for Safari too?

Comment: @The-VinhVO - have you tested?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I didn't experience the same on Safari, just Chrome, since this has been a very known change of Chrome 63. But I was curious to know if Safari has the same issue...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003617/mamp-redirects-virtual-localhost-to-https @VK321 : Can you please suggest if I am missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 63, will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header. ->
https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: I don't think its chrome. This behavior was for safari too.