# MAMP on Mac redirects virtual localhost to https

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp, virtualhost, macos-high-sierra

Chrome Version : 67.0.3396.87

Webserver : Apache

When I hit http://www.assignmenthelpdesk.local , it redirects to https://www.assignmenthelpdesk.local/

**How can I stop MAMP to redirect to https? Thanks in advance.**

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf details below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AssignmentHelpDesk
    ServerName www.assignmenthelpdesk.local
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts details

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.assignmenthelpdesk.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf details below:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Try to put "::1             localhost" line under comment section and also did you restart your MAMP?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? All settings are correct and should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working now.

I just had to remove the below two lines from .htaccess for assignmenthelpdesk (local folder)

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]